# Woocommerce - Shop Manager user delete capability

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Apparently only the administrator can delete users. The shop manager can only *edit* users (their info and password). I'd like the shop manager to be able to delete all users but administrators. The shop manager can't even delete the users he created.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

See the [`add_cap`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) function on how to add a capability to a role. [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities) is the list of available capabilities.

Another approach and albeit an easy one is to install a role editor plugin, for eg: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/ and then edit the 'Shop Manager' role and assign capabilities as required.

Answer (score 1):

Try to give following capabilities to shop manager:-

```
1. add_users
2. create_users
3. edit_users
4. list_users
```

This will allow manager to delete all the users except administrators